# Puzzled by Linear Regression Results from Spark ML and Tensorflow

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, tensorflow, linear-regression

I ran the this program: https://github.com/backstopmedia/tensorflowbook/blob/master/chapters/04_machine_learning_basics/linear_regression.py

I added "print("w=", W.eval(), "b=", b.eval())" after line 55 in above program. The result I got is:

w= [[ 3.5245235 ]
[ 1.50171268]] b= 1.14499

So  y=3.5245235x1 + 1.50171268x2 +1.14499.

I used the same data as above program (the file format is attached later), and ran the program https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/ml/JavaLinearRegressionWithElasticNetExample.java
the result is:

Coefficients: [0.3827266230806965,5.1690760222564425] Intercept: 82.22008153614573
numIterations: 6
objectiveHistory: [0.5,0.41583549697777683,0.15548328325638935,0.15439025905767773,0.15432368309706285,0.15432368309449543]

so y=0.3827266230806965x1+5.1690760222564425x2 + 82.22008153614573.

I am confused how the results are so different for the same problem? The data format I used the Spark program is:

```
354 1:84 2:46
190 1:73 2:20
405 1:65 2:52
263 1:70 2:30
451 1:76 2:57
302 1:69 2:25
288 1:63 2:28
385 1:72 2:36
402 1:79 2:57
365 1:75 2:44
209 1:27 2:24
290 1:89 2:31
346 1:65 2:52
254 1:57 2:23
395 1:59 2:60
434 1:69 2:48
220 1:60 2:34
374 1:79 2:51
308 1:75 2:50
220 1:82 2:34
311 1:59 2:46
181 1:67 2:23
274 1:85 2:37
303 1:55 2:40
244 1:63 2:30
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Tensorflow on simple linear regression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37281777/tensorflow-on-simple-linear-regression?rq=1). The code has the same issue. The fix will be the same as the answer there. Also, the learning_rate is too small (set it to .001) and steps need to be 100000. Choosing these initial values are very technical (one expert talked to me about this).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is quite simple, the spark model **is not** linear regression.

Linear regression minimizes || y - Wx ||_2^2

Spark model is **elastic net** which minimizes  || y - Wx ||_2^2
 + a1 || W ||_2^2 + a2 || W ||_1

If you want this spark code to be a linear regression **remove** the regularization terms:

```
  .setRegParam(0.3)
  .setElasticNetParam(0.8);
```

and increase amount of iterations to make sure it converges.

Comment: Not sure, I removed these two lines and .setMaxIter(1000). It seems it does not help much: Coefficients: [0.4173620987945001,5.21659080879135] Intercept: 77.
98253861487616
numIterations: 1
objectiveHistory: [0.0]

Comment: If we look at this: http://tempforum.neas-seminars.com/Attachment4373.aspx , I think the Spark ML's result is correct as @lejlot suggested. Can anybody fix the tensorflow code?